# Windows 10 use Python 3.9 over 3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I execute a `.py` script by double clicking it, my Windows 10 PC will use Python 3.9 over 3.10, although Python 3.9 is removed from the environment variables.
If I check the installed Python versions, it looks like this:

```
C:\Users\afflitio>py -0
Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows
 -3.10-64 *
 -3.9-64
```

What do I have to do to make my Windows 10 use Python 3.10 instead?

Comment: Uninstall Python 3.9 (unless you need it for other purposes) and make 3.10 your default

Comment: Ok yeah that worked. Still I wonder why it didn't work to select the Python 3.10 in the "open with..." file settings, but whatever.